# Laravel 3 no route working on Aruba

Tags: .htaccess, routes, laravel, laravel-3, aruba

I've developed a small app with Laravel 3. Locally (MAMP) it works perfectly, but when I uploaded it on my server (hosted by Aruba) and imported the database, I got the home page display correctly (also loading the database without any problems) but any route I try to access gives me back 404 error.
I also found that it's not Laravel's 404, with his messages like "We need a map" or so, it's the server's 404.
I think it may be something about .htaccess, but what?

Answer (score 1):

It happened to me with my hosting Tophost.
I solved this adding the line:

```
Rewritebase /path/to/public
```

In the .htaccess located in the public directory for example:

`Rewritebase /laravel/public`

I use Laravel 4, I'm not sure if it works with 3 too.